# Putnam and beyond section 2.3.2 example

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

In section 2.3.2 of the book ["Putnam and Beyond"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387257655) there is an example problem attributed to D. Andrica, for which I think the provided proof has an error.  In particular, it is asserted (on pg. 65) that $$ \prod_{\substack{i<j\\ i,j\neq k}} (x_j-x_i) = \frac{1}{p_k q_k},$$ where $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are any distinct reals, $$p_k = \prod_{i=0}^{n-(k+1)} (x_{n-i}-x_k),$$ and $$q_k = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (x_k - x_i).$$  This assertion seems to be false, e.g. if the $x_i$ are all integers, the left side is an integer, but the right side is $1/$integer.

Perhaps I'm missing something silly here.  If so, could someone please tell me what?  If I am correct and the proof is botched, can someone indicate how to fix the proof?

Comment: Since not all of us have access to the book, perhaps you can write down the original question from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be

$$ \prod_{\substack{i<j\\ i,j\neq k}} (x_j-x_i) = \frac{\prod_{\substack{i<j}} (x_j-x_i)}{p_k q_k}$$